# Patch a method in an Angular Material component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to change how MatRadioGroup works.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/radio/radio.ts)

I would like to overload the method `_updateSelectedRadioFromValue()`. How can I update this class without having to implement everything else in the class? Is there some way I can extend the class? Or patch the class?

Comment: If you are wondering if extending or patching classes is possible, or how those things are done, then you probably won't want to attempt either because it's not exactly simple. You haven't stated _why_ you want to do this - there might be a much easier way to achieve what you need.

Comment: there is a bug in that method. I want to change it.

Comment: What's the bug? Is it filed at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues? (Curious)

Comment: I just submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13432). But it would be faster for me to just fix it my self.

Comment: My guess is that will never be fixed. The right fix is a compare function option IMO, which is not trivial. They might add that to AM v7 (if they haven't already) but I doubt they'll do the work for v6 or v5. Just an opinion. EDIT: you _could_ workaround that problem by using constants for the season objects, but that might not be realistic in the real world especially if data comes from back end.

Comment: From what I can tell, the issue is not just the missing "compareWith" property. That would help probably. But the issue I see is that even though the `checked` property is `true` the radio button is not going into the checked state. This only happens when you try and set the value to a value that the form control is already set to. I believe with a small change to that method I mentioned in my post I could fix it, at least for my purposes. So that is why I asked how I can overwrite that method. I'll copy and paste the whole module if I have to... but I figured there would be an easier way.